# Browser maximize is not working in Karate-UI

Tags: karate

I am new to Karate UI and trying to maximize the chrome browser using Karate ZIP release(0.9.6RC4) on mac

I tried both with no luck

```
Given driver 'https://google.com'
And driver.maximize()
And maximize()
```

However fullscreen() is working fine, kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it seems to be a bug in Chrome itself. You can try this experiment:

```
* driver.send({"method":"Browser.setWindowBounds","params":{"windowId":1,"bounds":{"windowState":"minimized"}}})
```

Now replace `minimized` with `normal` or `maximized` and you will see `maximized` does not work. But it is supposed to as per the spec: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Browser/#method-setWindowBounds

This definitely used to work in previous versions of Chrome :)

We don't consider this a priority, feel free to raise a feature-request and also investigate if there is a known problem with Chrome. So I put the question back to you "kindly help". We need more open-source users to contribute.

Also note that driver type `chromedriver` works fine.

Comment: @NewDev no worries. also you may be able to simulate a maximize by getting the screen side and setting `driver.dimensions`